# What do you say in Latin when something sucks?

Tags: idiom

In English you can say: "This job/movie/party/[anything] sucks!"
This is a concise and slightly profane way of expressing displeasure.
Is there something similar in Latin?

The corresponding Finnish expression would literally translate to "This is from the deep!" which just goes to demonstrate that these idioms could be completely unrelated in different languages.
I don't expect *haurit* or *ab imo est* to make sense in Latin.

Is there a compact way to express displeasure with something in Latin, with a meaning similar to the English "sucks"?
It can be colloquial or literal language; the exact register doesn't matter.
I would like to be able to say "this movie sucks", "her new job sucks", "the weather here sucks", and similar.
There is of course *malus/mala/malum est*, but I was hoping there to be something a little more colorful and maybe stronger.

Comment: llmavirta: Yourself might need to begin by defining "sucks". Why is "sucking" something bad? Those who like to suck sweets, toffees, ice-cream cones; or, even, in a sexual sense might question this interpretation. If the desire is to bad-mouth someone/ something then: "How to Abuse & Insinuate in Classical Latin"/ Lovric & Mardas; and: "X-Treme Latin"/ Henry Beard. This latter first recommended by Flores on Q: How to Intensify a Phrase. Flores was voted down for this--why? Is it something for the Moderators?

Comment: @tony The English idiom doesn't make much sense literally. That's why I gave examples: I want to be able to say "this movie sucks", "her new job sucks", "the weather here sucks" and similar. I'll expand the question.

Comment: llmavirta: A lovely expression is "malis avibus" = "under bad birds". In the Roman World this was used in the sense of being under the influence of evil--going too far for your request, here? It's always tickled me; but, it's nothing to do with humour: "her new job is under bad birds"; you might just have started something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest *merda est!*, nicely mirroring the Romance expressions *è una merda* (It.), *c'est la merde* (Fr.) etc.

The following is an excerpt of Martial's Epigrams, Liber III, 17:

> *Circumlata diu mensis scribilita secundis
>
>   urebat nimio saeva calore manus;
>
>   sed magis ardebat Sabidi gula: protinus ergo
>
>   sufflavit buccis terque quaterque suis.
>
>   Illa quidem tepuit digitosque admittere visa est,
>
>   sed nemo potuit tangere: **merda fuit**.*
>
> A *scribilita* [a kind of sweet focaccia] that was moved around for long during the dessert, 
> burnt violently the hands with too much heat; but Sabidius's gluttony was more fired: 
> so he immediately blew on it three and four times. It certainly cooled down and seemed to be touchable, but nobody could eat it: it was [by then] shit.

One could object that Martial used the expression for food, and it might not make sense for something else. But I don't think so. Admittedly I couldn't find other instances of this phrase, but looking at Catullus' *Carmina*, Liber I, 36 I think it's safe to conclude the metaphor was pretty general for the Romans as it is for us moderns:

> *Annales Volusi, cacata charta,
> votum solvite pro mea puella.*
>
> Volusius' Annals, shit [literally "shat"] poem,
> fulfill the vow for my girl.

Comment: I agree with you, Vincenzo. Btw, I was wondering if the attested example of _cacata charta_ (rather than something like _merdosa charta_, which is perhaps not found until Medieval Latin) can be taken as it was _caca_ rather than _merda_ what was metaphorically extended in Vulgar Latin during Classical times. I'm noting this because of what you say in your post ("One could object that Martial used the expression for food, and it might not make sense for something else. But I don't think so").  In any case, the counterparts of Lat. _merda est_ and _caca est_ are extensively found in Romance.

Comment: Assuming that _merda est_ and _caca est_ were both extended metaphorically in Vulgar Latin during Classing times, it would also be interesting to work out whether a gradience similar to the one found in (Peninsular) Spanish and Catalan holds: cf. Sp. _Este film es una mierda_ ('This film sucks **a lot**') vs. _Sp. Este film es una caca_ ('This film sucks'), the former being 'stronger'/more forceful than the latter.

Comment: @Mitomino I think we find _cacata_ rather than _merdosa_ (or similar constructions revolving around _merda_) because Catullus did actually intend it as a past participle: a defecated poem, hence produced that way and not intellectually. It still shows the "excrement" metaphor works for different contexts: Catullus would agree that _Annales Volusi merda sunt_, wouldn't he? It seems the reconstructed Vulgar Latin noun is _*cacca_ - I do also wonder if _cacca est_ was  used like _merda est_, or even with different gradience, though it seems hard to even find any attestations of _cacca est_

Comment: Ok! Many thanks, Vincenzo, for your clarification remarks.

Comment: Nice find! As a small note on the English translation, *tepuit* should be "cooled down" rather than "got warm".

Comment: @TKR: Oh you're right, that's better! Thanks.